# Máscara em input ao carregar a página

Tags: javascript, javascript-eventos

Tenho uma página que exibe algumas informações do usuário. Um dos campos é o campo de telefone. Eu quero aplicar uma máscara nesse campo ao carregar a página. Até consigo colocar a máscara, mas apenas no evento onKeyUp. O problema é que a máscara só aparece quando eu aperto alguma tecla, e eu preciso que a máscara seja aplicada logo ao carregar a página.

Segue o JS.

```
        <!-- Script para máscara de telefone -->
    <script type="text/javascript">

        /* Máscaras ER */
        function mascara( o, f ){
            v_obj = o
            v_fun = f
            setTimeout( "execmascara()", 1 )
        }

        function execmascara(){
            v_obj.value = v_fun( v_obj.value )
        }

        function mtel( v ){
            v = v.replace( /\D/g, "" );                  // Remove tudo o que não é dígito
            v = v.replace( /^(\d{2})(\d)/g, "($1) $2" ); // Coloca parênteses em volta dos dois primeiros dígitos
            v = v.replace( /(\d)(\d{4})$/, "$1-$2" );    // Coloca hífen entre o quarto e o quinto dígitos

            return v;
        }

        function id( el ){
            return document.getElementById( el );
        }

        window.onload = function(){
            id( 'txt-telefone' ).onkeyup = function(){
                                                mascara( this, mtel );
                                            }
        }
    </script>
```

Como faço para a máscara aparecer ao carregar a página?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode pegar o seu objeto no onload e chamar a função, conforme abaixo:

```
var obj = document.getElementById("txt-telefone");
mascara(obj, mtel );
```

Ficando assim:

```
window.onload = function(){
  var obj = document.getElementById("txt-telefone");
  mascara(obj, mtel);

  id( 'txt-telefone' ).onkeyup = function(){
    mascara( this, mtel);
  }
}
```

**Dica:**

Existem frameworks mais fáceis de se trabalhar do que do jeito que você montou, que esta muito complexo para o que se deseja fazer.

Este é bem utilizado:
https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/